# Passing PHP variable in loop to another PHP file via hyperlink

Tags: php, mysql, variables, while-loop

This is essentially a rating system where some text is displayed, users click good/bad, and the database has a vote added or subtracted from it. I am currently trying to do it like this:

File #1 (rate.php) - prints random database row with text in. There is a 'good' hyperlink which goes to good.php and a 'bad' hyperlink which goes to bad.php.

File #2 (good.php or bad.php) - Clicking the links adds or removes a vote to/from the database as appropriate and returns to rate.php via the header function.

I am currently having difficulty passing the variable from the while loop to good.php and bad.php. Because they are hyperlinks, there is no form.

Should I even be using a while loop? Is there a better way to structure the whole thing? Does this call for sessions?

**EDIT:**

Here is the while loop.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM challenges WHERE visible = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<div id='box'>";
    echo $row['challenge'];
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div style='text-align: center; font-size: 12px;'>
<span id='good'><a href='good.php'>good</a></span> &nbsp;
<span id='skip'><a href='rate.php'>skip</a></span> &nbsp;
<span id='bad'><a href='bad.php'>bad</a></span></div>";
}
```

Comment: are you looking for $_GET? or $_POST ?

Comment: You should post some code. I haven't the slightest clue about what your while-loop dilemma is.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just pass a row ID with GET variable

```
good.php?row_id=12345
bad.php?row_id=12345
```

in good.php and bad.php it becomes a variable like:

```
$_GET['row_id']
```

Comment: @Sebastian - That's just bad practice.. you should really use POST instead. Make a button named good and one named bad. Wrap them in a form and then in your rate.php page add the code for when the user submits using the good button, and then using the bad button

Comment: i also recommend to POST this variable, but as long as @Sebastian want to do this via links, it's the easiest way